# Replacing for loop with stream to add correctly and incorrectly spelled words

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, java-stream

I am trying to replace this for loop with a stream that adds correctly spelled words to `spelledCorrectly` and incorrectly spelled words to `misspelled`

```
    for (String e : incoming) {
        if (dict.contains(e.toLowerCase()))
            spelledCorrectly.add(e.toLowerCase());
        else if (!"".equals(e.toLowerCase().trim())) {
            misspelled.add(e);
        }
    }
```

And here is what I have tried, but I am getting errors on the `.map` and `.collect` lines and I am unsure how to fix them.

```
    incoming.stream()
        .filter(e -> dict.contains(e.toLowerCase()))
        .map(spelledCorrectly::getId)
        .collect(toList());

    incoming.stream()
        .filter(e -> !"".equals(e.toLowerCase().trim()))
        .map(misspelled::getId)
        .collect(toList());
```

should i use different pipelines?

Comment: `spelledCorrectly.add` and `spelledCorrectly::getId` what datatype is spelledCorrectly of?

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, but it looks like you are trying to call a `getId` method on a `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rab is right! But for correct behavior, I updated a little:

```
incoming.stream()
        .filter(dict::contains)
        .forEach(spelledCorrectly::add);

incoming.stream()
        .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty() && !dict.contains(e.toLowerCase()))
        .forEach(misspelled::add);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your above piece of code, spelledCorrectly and mispelled are local variables already present before the loop:

```
incoming.stream()
    .filter(e ->   dict.contains(e.toLowerCase())).forEach(e->spelledCorrectly.add(e));

incoming.stream()
    .filter(e -> !"".equals(e.toLowerCase().trim())).forEach(misspelled.add(e));
```

would be the correct translation of your loop to streams

Answer (score 0):

While I think ernest (looks like he/she deleted the answer) answer is a good once, I decided to convert your loop to stream,

```
    incoming.stream()
            .filter(dict::contains)
            .forEach(spelledCorrectly::add);

    incoming.stream()
            .filter(e -> !e.isEmpty())
            .forEach(misspelled::add);
```

this should do the same thing as what you are doing in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

You could first sanitize your words and filter out the empty ones, then collect them to a partition:

```
Map<Boolean, List<String>> result = incoming.stream()
    .map(String::trim)
    .map(String::toLowerCase)
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(dict::contains));
```